# force the maven site plugin to use specific java version?

Tags: java, maven

Is there any way to force the [maven site plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/) to use a specific java version?

I have java 8, but I need to force it to use java 7 for `site-deploy`ing.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Java 7 and 8 on the same computer. Set environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to the Java 7 installation and start maven normally.

Comment: What I am looking for is a parameter set inside the maven definition inside my `pom.xml`, rather than changing your `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Well, that plugin doesn't have options to set the JVM, so.... if you're on Linux you can just execute `env JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java mvn site:deploy ....` to run just a single maven command with 7.